# How do I create a new txt file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a new txt file in powershell and then write some text to it. Where will the output be palced? Im using the ISE to test and it isnt outputing the file in the same place that the script is located. There isnt much code but I included it below.

```
$text = "<Html><Header></Header><Body>Hello World!</Body></Html>"

$text|Set-Content 'file.txt'
```

Comment: Your home directory, you can get that by running `pwd` in ISE.

Comment: It would seem to me that you could have figured this out yourself. `$text|Set-Content 'SomeStrangeFileName.xyz` and then a Windows search for the file should have found the location, I'd think. A post to SO is not always necessary to resolve trivial issues.

Comment: It will put it in the current working directory (which you can display using $PWD), but that's not the same as your Home directory (which you can display using $HOME). The ISE will open initially to your Home directory, but if you change directory (using cd or set-location) your $PWD will change, but $Home will remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output the file to the same directory as the script is located use the `$PSScriptRoot` variable e.g:

```
$text | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\file.txt
```